# String length not getting updated after new input

Tags: string, sockets

iam trying to implement a simple TCP server-client model....

Client :

```
while (fgets(sendline, 4096, stdin) != NULL) {
printf("\n %s \n ",sendline);   //check
printf("\n %d \n ",strlen(sendline)); //check
send(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline), 0);
```

Server :

```
while ( (n = recv(connfd, buf, 4096,0)) > 0)  {
printf("%s","String received from and resent to the client:"); 
printf ("\n %d \n ",strlen(buf)); //check
puts(buf);      
send(connfd, buf, n, 0);
```

the out put is :
client */$ ./TCPclient.out 127.0.0.1

mon tue

mon tue

8

String received from the server: mon tue

mon

mon

4

String received from the server: mon
tue

*/
String received from and resent to the client:

8

mon tue

String received from and resent to the client:

8

mon

tue

*/

when first string is given as input the string length is  8, but after second input i.e "mon" the string length should be 4 in server too but it retains the previous string length :( .......please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the string from the file in Client, you read the exact number of bytes, i.e. not including a null terminator, so the string 'hello' is sent as five bytes.

When the recv call is made in Server, it reads five bytes and puts them in to a buffer, but it will just overwrite the first five bytes, so what is actually there is 'helloxxx' where 'xxx' is the garbage left over from the first call.

So if you really want to consider all received data to be an ASCII string then you need to append a null terminator to the buffer at position 'n' after recv.

Comment: yesss.......thank you!! for your speedy answer.......
 the edit needed to make was..


send(sockfd, sendline, strlen(sendline) + **1**, 0);

Comment: Mark my answer as 'Accepted' then please :)